# Show that if $(x_{n})$ is bounded sequence then $(x_{n})$ if and only if lim sup$(x_{n})$=lim inf$(x_{n})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I stuck this problem I can only proof first partbut can't prove the second part
first part lim sup $(x_{n})$=lim inf$(x_{n})$ then limit of sequence is exist.
Since limit exist the sequence must be bounded sequence

Comment: $x_n=(-1)^n$ is bounded, but $\varliminf\neq\varlimsup$

Comment: @zwim I stuck at that point  because I can't find th condition that is guarantee it is  monotonic sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is not true and i agree to @zwim 
 you can see another example $$x_n=n$$ here $$\text{limsup}(x_n) = \text{liminf}(x_n) = ∞$$ but sequence is not bounded

Comment: Please try to write your answers as clearly as you can. For that you must use proper formatting.

Comment: ok @StubbornAtom next time i will

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you want to prove that $\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n$ exists if and only if $\liminf_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n=\limsup_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n$.

If $\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n$ exists, than both $\liminf_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n$ and $\limsup_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n$ are equal to it and therefore they are equal to each other.

If, on the other and, there is a number $l\in\mathbb R$ such that $\liminf_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n=\limsup_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n=l$, take $\varepsilon>0$. Since $l+\varepsilon>l=\limsup_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n$, then the inequality $x_n<l+\varepsilon$ holds for all but a finite number of natural numbers $n$. And since $l-\varepsilon<l=\liminf_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n$, then the inequality $x_n>l-\varepsilon$ holds for all but a finite number of natural numbers $n$. Therefore, there is a natural number $p$ such that $n\geqslant p\Longrightarrow l-\varepsilon<x_n<l+\varepsilon\Longleftrightarrow|l-x_n|<\varepsilon$.